# Canonical averages in a Fermi gas aka generalized Fermi-Dirac distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, research-level, quantum-statistics

I am in the process of applying [Beenakker's](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v44/i4/p1646_1) tunneling master equation theory of quantum dots (with some generalizations) to some problems of non-adiabatic charge pumping. As a part of this work I encounter thermal averages of single-particle quantities  with a fixed total number of electrons. They are pretty straightforward to derive, as recently discussed on Physics.SE, see [Combinatorial sum in a problem with a Fermi gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/combinatorial-sum-in-a-problem-with-a-fermi-gas/13765#13765).

I have trouble finding references to prior work for this basic quantum statistics problem. Can you suggest  some relevant references in this context?

**Progress report:**

Writing this stuff up, I realized that I'm basically asking for finite electron number and finite level spacing generalization of the Fermi function:

$\langle \nu_k \rangle = Z_n^{-1} \sum_{n=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-m} Z_m  e^{-\beta \epsilon_k( n-m)}$
where  $Z_n$ is the $n$-electron canonical partition function.

For either $n \gg 1$ <strike>or</strike> and $\epsilon_{k+1}-\epsilon_k \ll \beta^{-1}$ this reduces to the standard Fermi-Dirac distribution:

$\langle \nu_k \rangle= \frac{1}{1+z_0 e^{-\beta \epsilon_k}}$

The advantage of the new formula is that it only depends on $k$ via $e^{-\beta \epsilon_k}$ with all the combinatorics hidden in $Z_n$. This is unlike the textbook expression [summarized in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Derivation_starting_with_canonical_distribution), or Beenakker's  implicit function $F(E_p |n)$ (which is $\langle \nu_p \rangle$ in notation).

The question still stands: I don't believe the first formula above is new, what is the right reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A particle-number projection method which is based on Fourier transform of the grand-canonical partition function has been developed by Ormand *et al.* [Phys. Rev. C 49, 1422 (1994)](http://prc.aps.org/abstract/PRC/v49/i3/p1422_1) in the context of nuclear quantum Monte-Carlo simulations. This gives a closed form formula which scales quadratically in the number of levels. It has been used by Alhassid *et al.* [Phys. Rev. B 58, R7524 (1998)](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v58/i12/pR7524_1) to describe (numerically) deviations from Fermi-Dirac distribution, see Eq. (140) in Alahssid's [review paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0102268).

Since the approach described in the question appears to be new, I've [posted it to the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6264). For equidistant (1d harmonic oscillator) spectrum, generalization of Fermi-Dirac distribution leads to an intriguing series of polynomials and Rogers-Ramanujan partial theta function, see [math.SE discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73284/).